# Rails 5: check box tag showing up two times

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I use custom check box styling for my application, the problem I'm currently facing is that the custom check box style is rendered and the normal bootstrap check box.

As you can guess the custom check box is not clickable, but showing up.

Here is an example for the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <strong class="container_check version_2">Ebay Angebot?
    <%= check_box_tag :ebay_offer, true, [] %>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </strong>
</div>
```

This is what the console throws out:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ebay_offer" id="ebay_offer" value="true" checked="checked">
```

The corresponding bootstrap class (not my custom checkmark):

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]
```

My custom checkmark class

```
  /** CHECKMARKS */
 .container_check {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    padding-left: 30px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
 }


 .container_check input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer
 }

 .container_check input:checked~.checkmark {
    background-color: #2FE7B1;
    border: 1px solid transparent
 }

 .container_check .checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #d2d8dd;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
 }

 .container_check .checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 7px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg)
 }

 .container_check.version_2 {
    padding: 6px 0 0 45px;
    min-height: 30px
 }

 .container_check.version_2 .checkmark {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px
 }

 .container_check.version_2 .checkmark:after {
    left: 12px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px
 }

 .container_check input:checked~.checkmark:after {
    display: block
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite often with this kind of thing the span needs to be within the field or within the label. You could try formats like these:

```
<%= check_box_tag :ebay_offer, true, [] do %>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= label_tag :ebay_offer do %>
  <%= check_box_tag :ebay_offer %>
  Any desired label text <span class="checkmark"></span>
<% end %>
```